# How does recursion work in void method java

Tags: recursion, java

```
class test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  int n = 5;
  mystery(n);
}

  public static void mystery(int n)
{

  if(n == 0 || n==1)
  {
   return;
  }
  mystery(n-2);
  System.out.println(n);
  mystery(n-1);
  }
}
```

This a very simple void method code.

I want to know what happen during the recursion and why is the output is like that??

the output to the console is:

3

2

5

2

4

3

2

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following binary tree `mystery-tree(5)`

```
         5
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     4       3
    / \     /
   /   \   /
  3     2 2
 / 
2
```

Clearly `mystery-tree(5)` is defined by:

```
mystery-tree(1) = null
mystery-tree(2) = null
mystery-tree(n) = Node n mystery-tree(n - 1) mystery-tree(n - 2)
```

Clearly the output you showed is just the reversed in-order traversal of this tree, i.e. `mystery(n) = for i in reversed(in-order(mystery-tree(n))) { println(n) }`.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: The hope is that decomposing the function makes it less of a mystery. This directly addresses the second question.